# How to keep rows with the same values in two variables in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with several variables, but I want to keep the rows that are the same based on two columns. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
a <- c(rep('A',3), rep('B', 3), rep('C',3))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,4,4,5,5,5)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

  a b
1 A 1
2 A 1
3 A 2
4 B 4
5 B 4
6 B 4
7 C 5
8 C 5
9 C 5
```

I know that if I use the duplicated function I can get:

```
df[!duplicated(df),]

  a b
1 A 1
3 A 2
4 B 4
7 C 5
```

But since the level 'A' on column `a` does not have a unique value in `b`, I want to drop both observations to get a new data.frame as this:

```
  a b
4 B 4
7 C 5
```

I don't mind to have repeated values across `b`, as long as for every same level on `a` there is the same value in `b`.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one maybe?

```
ag <- aggregate(b~a, df, unique)
ag[lengths(ag$b)==1,]

#  a b
#2 B 4
#3 C 5
```

Comment: This does not test if 'A' values are in `b`

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thanks but what do you mean?

Comment: multiple b values for A are sufficient to discard all A rows. This does that fine.

Comment: Try it with my data.frame I commented above. It leaves duplicate b's across a's. I assume that OP doesn't want this either. (I may be wrong, but OP should clarify).

Comment: This is a case where the OP makes an example that is too simplified and attracts solutions that answer the specific case but do not internalize the logic.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Then I think the OP should clarify the logic better.

Comment: But what do you get from this??: `But since the level 'A' on column a does not have a unique value in b, I want to drop both observations`

Comment: Better to wait for OP for clarity

Comment: @989 Yes, I don't mind to have repeated values across "b", as long as for every same level on "a" there is the same value in b.

Comment: If 'A' had `1` and `4`, would it have been deleted?

Comment: @PierreLafortune Yes!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
> ind <- apply(sapply(with(df, split(b,a)), diff), 2, function(x) all(x==0) )
> out <- df[!duplicated(df),]
> out[out$a %in% names(ind)[ind], ]
  a b
4 B 4
7 C 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(b)==1) .SD[1L], by = a]
#   a b
#1: B 4
#2: C 5
```